# pyproj fails to compile when i pip install it. And it's not about gcc

Tags: python, pyproj

It throws errors that make it seems like there's something really wrong about the code, such as :

```
 _proj.c:7486:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_type’; did you mean ‘curexc_type’?
     tstate->exc_type = local_type;
             ^~~~~~~~
             curexc_type
_proj.c:7487:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_value’; did you mean ‘curexc_value’?
     tstate->exc_value = local_value;
             ^~~~~~~~~
             curexc_value
_proj.c:7488:13: error: ‘PyThreadState’ {aka ‘struct _ts’} has no member named ‘exc_traceback’; did you mean ‘curexc_traceback’?
     tstate->exc_traceback = local_tb;
```

It is pyproj version 1.9.5.1

Answer (score 5):

These files are generated by Cython. Try upgrading Cython to the version that supports your Python and regenerate files. (Cython >= 0.27.3 for Python 3.7)

**EDIT:**

[This thread](https://github.com/jswhit/pyproj/issues/136) recommends installing pyproj by pointing to the git repo of pyproj.

```
pipenv install cython
pipenv install git+https://github.com/jswhit/pyproj.git#egg=pyproj
```

By installing from Git, Cython will recompile necessary c files.

Comment: Hi, thanks, still getting errors. Only one this time, though: src/projects.h:113:25: error: ‘M_2_PI’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘M_PI’?
   #define M_TWO_D_PI      M_2_PI                   /* 2/pi */